# Difference between schema-based and ORM

Tags: mongodb, entity-framework, mongoose

I have a question here that what is the difference between **schema-based solution** and **ORM** like EntityFrameWork is an ORM and Mongoose is an schema-based solution. Both of them are the same thing or not ? if not then why ?

Answer (score 1):

At a very basic level, yes, they do have *some* common functionality.

A 'full-fat' ORM, like entity framework will have alot more that simple record to object mapping though.

for example, EF can take data from several tables and map them to a single class, it can supply validation, linking and other useful stuff at the application layer which Mongoose, or the MongoC#Driver cannot do.